# Is there a pure-CSS hack to activate “text-align: justify” only if the browser supports “hyphens: auto”?

Tags: css, hyphenation

The [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#Browser_compatibility) for `hyphens: auto` is still a bit lacking, even for English, but I would like to provide it already to my visitors using Firefox. If the browser does not support it, however, the gaps in the justified text are unseemly wide, and I would rather fall back on flush left alignment.

This is essentially what the CSS code looks like.

```
p {
    text-align: justify;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

I’m aware of JavaScript libraries like [Hyphenator.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/) that provide hyphenation for a range of browsers, but is there maybe a pure CSS solution for my simpler use case? I’ve come to think of hyphenation as less than essential on the web, unfortunately, and don’t want to embed a JavaScript library if there is a simpler fallback solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new @supports property can do it, however that is not supported by all browsers either. If you are willing to accept that as a limitation you can look at the Mozilla Docs here: 
[@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)

Comment: Sort of, but `@supports` isn't *quite* as useful/rigorous as we might hope: [http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2013/03/19/unsupportable-promises/](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2013/03/19/unsupportable-promises/). (Albeit this is the closest approach that CSS offers to meet this requirement.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I’m using `@supports ((hyphens: auto) or (-webkit-hyphens: auto) or (-moz-hyphens: auto)) { /* Definitions as above */ }`, and it works as expected in Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: Setting the `lang` html attribute to `de-DE` broke the hyphenation for the mobile browser I tested. Firefox was fine with it. Setting  `lang="de"` fixed this issue. Hope this helps someone looking this up again ;)